# created live tile looks corrupt

Tags: isolatedstorage, corrupt, live-tile

am creating custom live tiles by updating the text in a 173x173 XAML control, then using writablebitmap.Render to create a JPEG. Finally, create StandardTileData, set the two images, and put them on the correct tile. Works most of the time. Actually it always updates fine. But once in a while when a new tile is created, or deleted, the image is corrupted. The text is all mushed on the left side of the tile and there is no background color.
Any ideas what could be happening? It's not a background task as that is disabled. Something to do with the system scanning the newly created jpegs while I'm trying to set the tile data?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

found solution here
[rendering usercontrol live tile windows phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14357302/rendering-usercontrol-live-tile-windows-phone)
Obviously a system bug. 
calling UpdateLayout before and after each measure and arrange call